# Grafana Datasource not loading environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, grafana, systemd, grafana-variable

I am trying to create a datasource in Grafana by connecting Grafana with my PostgreSQL Database. Following the instructions of the official Grafana Website, i configured my datasource in the datasource.yml file as shown bellow:

```
datasources:
  - name: PostgreSQL
    type: postgres
    url: db-web.com:5432
    database: $DB
    user: $USER
    secureJsonData:
      password: $PASSWORD
```

The environmental variables i saved in a file called /etc/grafana/environment:

```
USER=myuser
PASSWORD=mypassword
DB=mydb
```

I then added this file containing the environment variables in my grafana.service file:

```
...
[service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/grafana/environment
...
```

When i restart the grafana service, i can see the datasource is created, but it won't connect to the databse, because the variables are not loaded. If i give them in clear text in the datasource.yml file, then it works. So i assume the problem is with the loading of the environment files. Do you have any idea what i could have configured wrong and if there is any other way to solve this issue?

Many Thanks in advance!